# Не происходит запись в файл из-за отсутствия прав

Tags: php, permissions

Пытаюсь записать логи в директории, но получаю ошибку:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

Установил права `777` на директорию, в которой лежит исполняемый PHP-файл и лог-файл, и всё заработало. Но насколько безопасно использовать полные права на папку?

```
$file = fopen('debug-' . date('G:i_Y-m-d') . '.log', "w") or die('Unable to write debug data into a log file');
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте права на папку 777, а на файлы 666 - без права на исполнение

Если кто-то создаст папку в папке которая с правами 777, то эта папка будет уже не с такими правами, так что вы следите за файлами, которые лежат непосредственно в папке с правами 777, в другом не вижи никаких опасений.

Comment: На `.php`-файле сейчас стоят права 644.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin это значит только для чтения, вы его не сможете изменить. Однако вы сможете его перезаписать, если он лежит в директории с правами 777

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Можете ещё, дать папке права 700, а файлу 666, таким образом, право за файл будет у создателя и root

Answer (score 0):

Давать права 777 на директорию с php не очень удачная идея, хотя чтобы там нахулиганить нужны еще другие дырки. Кладите логи в отдельную директорию, в которой хотя бы отключен обработчик php. Также если вам не нужно просматривать лог через HTTP стОит запретить доступ к этой директории по HTTP

Comment: А ещё лучше лог файлы выносить за пределы сайта, например в tmp папку, не правда ли?)

Comment: @Daniil лог лучше выносить за пределы сервера. https://12factor.net/logs